# Accept an array with n elements and return them as an array - Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I would like to write a function that accepts an array of any number of values and returns their changed values in a new array.

```
function zArray = y(xArray)
    zArray = [];
    for x = 1:size(xArray,2)
        if x >= -2 && x < -1
            z = ln(x + 2);
        elseif x >= -1 && x < 0
            z = (x + 1).^2;
        elseif x >= 0 && x <= 2
            z = (x + 1)/(x.^2 + 1);
        else 
            z = -10
        end
        zArray(end + 1) = z;
    end
end
```

I then call the function with:

```
[z1, z2, z3] = y([0, 1, -1])
```

Which gives me the following output and message:

```
z1 =

    1.00000    0.60000  -10.00000

error: element number 2 undefined in return list
```

I am new to Matlab and am not sure how Matlab for loops and arrays work. If I understand correctly, I am not adding the changed values correctly to the array which is supposed to hold output values and therefore can not read them in this manner, but if I am not mistaken, `array(end + 1) = z` is appending the element `z` to the end of the array.

Am I making more than one mistake? Please point out any of them because I have troubles understanding the Matlab syntax, even though I do know how to program in some other languages.

Comment: Do you want to add changed values from back of the z array?

Comment: Your first and second `if` and `elseif` statements  are redundant here. If you explain what to do, I can help you

Comment: I want to add them at the end, so they are in the same order as they were before changing them. I want to achieve output [f(x1), f(x2), ..., f(xn)] from [x1, x2, ..., xn], where f is an interval function.

Comment: Then you don't need to add them from the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you desire the following thing but you are confused with syntax:

```
function zArray = y(xArray)
zArray = zeros(size(xArray));

for x = 1:size(xArray,2)
    xVal = xArray(x);
    if xVal >= -2 && xVal < -1
        zArray(x) = log(xVal + 2);
    elseif xVal >= -1 && xVal < 0
        zArray(x) = (xVal + 1).^2;
    elseif xVal >= 0 && xVal <= 2
        zArray(x) = (xVal + 1)/(xVal.^2 + 1);
    else
        zArray(x) = -10;
    end
end
end
```